# Mysql won't work on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I had installed mysql on ubuntu. But supposedly the password I remembered is not the actual password. I tried to change it, reinstall it. But nothing works.

Whenever I try something the terminal even takes a new password but then it goes like...
150922 16:13:05 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) starting as process 22649 ...

The terminal's like this for like a few minutes.

And then it simply tells me in the end that it is unable to change the password.

Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user. An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server. You should check the account's password after the package installation. Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I far as I know, if we lost the password, it can't recover otherwise it is not a secured database. My suggestion better to reinstall the MySQl.

Comment: I did reinstall. But it again takes a new password but then returns the same error message as above.

Comment: Hi just try with blank password.

Comment: Here are steps to set mysql password Please check it out http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/